# Find the rows that contain a common pair of values in a dataframe and merge them by a third column

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
Source<-c("DB","DB","DB","TC","TC","TC")
Drug<-c("a","a","c","d","a","c")
Target<-c("asd","asd","dch","dfg","asd","vgh")
file<-data.frame(Source,Drug,Target)

Source Drug Target

    1     DB    a    asd
    2     DB    a    asd
    3     DB    c    dch
    4     TC    d    dfg
    5     TC    a    asd
    6     TC    c    vgh
```

And my goal is to create a dataframe -and therefore a csv file- which will detect which rows have the same pair of "Drug", "Target" between 2 different "Source" and merge these rows into one in order to achieve the form below. If a pair exists more than once in a "Source" -for example a-asd in DB- should not be kept twice. The dataframe above is just a sample as there may be a pair that exists in more that 2 sources-for example if `a-asd` exists in 6 sources then the new merged value should be something like `DB|TC|AD|SD|FG|FH`

```
Source Drug Target
1  DB|TC    a    asd
2     DB    c    asd
3     TC    d    dfg
4     TC    c    vgh


fwrite(x = file22,file = 'Output.csv',na='NA')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
file%>%
   group_by(Drug,Target)%>%
   summarise(Source=glue::collapse(unique(Source),"|"))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Drug [?]
  Drug  Target Source
  <fct> <fct>  <chr> 
1 a     asd    DB|TC 
2 c     dch    DB    
3 c     vgh    TC    
4 d     dfg    TC
```